# UIImagePickerController delegate warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting this warning when setting the delegate of a picker view:

```
 UIImagePickerController *pickerLibrary = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    pickerLibrary.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    pickerLibrary.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:pickerLibrary animated:YES completion:nil];



warning : assigning to <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationBarDelegate> from incompatible type "photoBrowser(my class name)
```

I have registered to the delegates:

```
@interface PhotoBrowser : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationBarDelegate>
```

Tried also:

```
@interface PhotoBrowser : UIImagePickerController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationBarDelegate>
```

1-The error don't go away ..

2- How and when do I ask the user for permission? I somehow couldn't find 1 simple guide to open this library and choose image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't it `UINavigationControllerDelegate` instead of `UINavigationBarDelegate`?

The ask user for permission thing is automatically handled by iOS system when you try to open the image picker. It'll show an alert popup.